# Dissipation of energy in inductors

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation, electrical-resistance, inductance, dissipation

Please explain the dissipation of energy in a circuit containing a resistance and inductor after the switched in the circuit is opened.I mean how do you explain that the energy that is across inductor gets dissipated without any further closed circuit?

Comment: Please include a schematic diagram of your circuit so we can understand what is the effect of opening the switch?

Comment: Here is an article on the effect  of inductive loads on switches. Hope it helps.http://www.artisancontrols.com/UtilityImages/ProductSupportPdf/Switching%20Inductive%20Loads.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A schematic is needed to give a complete answer, but consider the following:

The voltage across an ideal inductor is given by

$$V(t)=L\frac{dI(t)}{dt}$$

The inductor will therefore generate a high voltage to resist a large change in current which would be the case in attempting to open the circuit with a switch. If the switch is an air gap type, the inductor will create a high enough voltage to create an arc across the switch contacts, ionizing the air in the gap and allowing current to flow through the ionized air. The energy stored in the inductors magnetic field is thus dissipated in the combination of the arc and the series resistor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @JustyLaurent Answer was acceptable?

Comment: What if the arc does not happen and the current does not continue through the gap?

Comment: @JánLalinský But it does happen. Switches that control inductive loads have to have special inductive load ratings since arcing due to inductive loads can damage the contacts.

Comment: It happens if the electric field is strong enough. If not, the air behaves as isolator and there is no arc.

Comment: @JánLalinský Here is an article on the effects of inductive loads on switches.http://www.artisancontrols.com/UtilityImages/ProductSupportPdf/Switching%20Inductive%20Loads.pdf

Comment: The switches that you mention have very close terminals so the electric field in between is very strong. However, what would happen if the circuit is disconnected and the terminals get very far from each other so the arc gets immediately extinguished? What happens to the energy of the coil?

Comment: @JánLalinský Keep in mind also that air gap switches do not open all the way instantaneously. Upon the beginning of opening the air gap is very small and therefore the voltage need not be very high to start the arcing process. In addition to the air conducting, there can be some metal plasma generated due to the high localized temperatures on the contact material.

Comment: That is true, but current also does not discharge instantaneously. What if I have a breaker that removes the terminals so fast that arc is gone before the current is zero? Or, there can be a gas blower to extinguish the arc very fast. What happens to stored inductor energy then?